# Christian origins reference request

Tags: hebrew

Can anyone provide a source that says to the effect that Christianity and Judaism originate from a religion that existed in Israel in the 1st millennium BC that called their God something that in English might have sounded like Yahweh?
(I asked the same question on biblical hermeneutics [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74832/christian-origins-reference-request), but was closed as off topic)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this web page will answer your question:

https://biblescienceforum.com/tag/paleo-hebrew-yhwh/

YHWH The Creator God
Post author
By John Gideon Hartnett
Post date
February 3, 2014

This page provides a photograph of the Paleo-Hebrew Tetragrammaton (10th century BCE to 135 CE).

> “And God said unto Moses, I AM THAT I AM: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto you.”  Exodus 3:14

The Hebrew word here for “I AM” is Hayah (pronounced ‘haw-yaw‘), meaning “to exist”

Many scholars believe that the most proper meaning of YHWH may be “He Brings Into Existence Whatever Exists” (Yahweh-Asher-Yahweh). In I Samuel, God is known by the name Yahweh Teva-‘ot, or “He Brings the Hosts Into Existence” – the hosts possibly referring to the heavenly court or to Israel (see 1 Samuel 17:45). This personal name of God was probably known long before the time of Moses.

God is Himself without cause. He created all things.

You can also checkout: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahweh.

This page states that:

> The origins of his worship reach at least to the early Iron Age, and likely to the Late Bronze Age.

There is too much history on this page to mention it here. But the dates for the bronze and iron ages are:

- Bronze: 1550–1200 BCE
- Iron Age I: 1200–1000 BCE
- Iron Age II: 1000–586 BCE